# Add a submodule to each branch of a parent project

Tags: git-branch, git-submodules, git-untracked

I have a project called `channel`, which has only one branch -- master. And I have another project called `bigTest`, which has four branches -- master, dev, stable, release.
Nowadays I want to add `channel` to the root directory of `bigTest` as a submodule of each branch of `bigTest`. I used `git submodule add <url>` for each branch of four. However I got
`modified:   channel (untracked content)` and modified `.gitmodules` appending `branch = dev` even though I used `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.channel.branch dev` on dev branch.
What should I do in order to add a submodule master to multiple branches of a project? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `submodule.channel.branch` should be set to `master` only, since the remote submodule repo (channel) has only one branch to follow anyway.

Once declared, you need add, commit and push from bigTest, since the `.gitmodules` has changed, and a gitlink (special entry in the index) representing channel root folder has been created.

> However `git status` shows: `Untracked files: (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) channel/` when I checkout `master` of `bigTest`.

The OP finds out why:

> Yes, I compile and produce something in the submodule folder.
>   I can conclude that Git will show untracked content if something new created from submodules.

I recommend putting what is produce in the `.gitignore` of the submodule.

Comment: I can still not add ```channel``` to index in *dev*, *stable* or *release* branch of ```bigTest``` repo, showing ```modified:   channel  (untracked content)```. However ```git status``` shows: ```Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 channel/
``` when I checkout master of ```bigTest```. That seems like I could add and commit ```channel``` submodule to master of ```bigTest```.

Comment: @BryanYU what git status shows when executed from within the channel submodule folder?

Comment: You make sense! There are something left in submodule. After I commit them in submodule, ```modified:   Channel_ANS_test (new commits)``` is shown in ```bigTest``` directory. Thank you! What should I do? I should push changes to remote in submodule and then commit and push changes to remote in parent repo.

Comment: Strange, there should not be anything "changed" in the submodule folders. But if you do commit inside a submodule, you should push to the submodule remote repo, then go to the main parent repo, add, commit and push as well.

Comment: Yes, I compile and produce sth. in the submodule folder. I can conclude that the git will show ```untracked content``` if something new created from submodules.

Comment: You could add what you are producing in the .gitignore of the submodule repo.

Comment: @BryanYU I have edited the answer to reflect those comments and their conclusion.

Comment: that's awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @BryanYU No problem. Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.